# Few lines of code causing a SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm using the `UITableView` delegate to dynamically resize my `UITableViewCells` but for some reason the following bit of code is giving me an abort signal. Are there any obvious issues with it?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *comment = [_comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return expectedLabelSize.height;

}
```

Comment: You rarely get a SIGABRT without an error message. Check the console for logs, most likely an uncaught exception.

Comment: `_comments` is probably a pointer to a deallocated object but it's impossible to say unless you identify that that is the line causing your crash and show how you create, populate, and release `_comments`.

Comment: @Jonah @ughoavgfhw it is the `CGSize` line. `_comments` is not deallocd. Found the answer though! I added an `NSLog` of the `comment` string and found that the string was equal to `<SocializeComment: 0x5d79970>` or something else along those lines. Changing the `CGSize` assignment to `[[comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0] text]` from `[comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]` fixed this. Can anyone shed any light as to what happend there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `CGSize` assignment to

`[[comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0] text]`

from

`[comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]` fixed it.

Comment: How did that fix it? It looks like you're trying to call `text` on a `CGSize`!